# Flink - Why does Flink throw error when I submit job by 'flink run' after running Flink stand-alone more than 1 month?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm running Flink in stand-alone mode on 1 host (JobManager, TaskManager on the same host). At first, I'm able to submit and cancel jobs normally, the jobs showed up in the web UI and ran.

However, after ~1month, when I canceled the old job and submitting a new one, I faced **org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not retrieve the execution result.**

At this moment, I was able to run **flink list** to list current jobs and **flink cancel** to cancel the job, but **flink run** failed. Exception was thrown and the job was now shown in the web UI.

When I tried to stop the current stand-alone cluster using **stop-cluster**, it said 'no cluster was found'. Then I had to find the pid of flink processes and stop them manually. Then if I run **start-cluster** to create a new stand-alone cluster, I was able to submit jobs normally.

The shortened stack-trace: (full stack-trace at [google docs link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v07A4Jp45worykjgMyQTVR-BAoPXwL-O9qGxxhNjXyE/edit?usp=sharing))

`org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not retrieve the execution result. (JobID: 7ef1cbddb744cd5769297f4059f7c531)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob (RestClusterClient.java:261) 
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.                                      Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.ConnectionClosedException: Channel became inactive. 
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.ConnectionClosedException: Channel became inactive.
        ... 37 more`

The error is consistent. It always happens after I let Flink run for a while, usually more than 1 month). Why am I not able to submit job to flink after a while? What happened here?